# Save CustomDocumentProperties without saving the document

Tags: vba, powerpoint, custom-properties

I am trying to store some values creating a CustomDocumentProperty in VBA. The problem is that every time I want to change the value if I close the presentation without saving it, when I open the value doesn't save. Is there any possibility to save just this CustomDocumentProperty without saving all the document?

Comment: not, it's not possible. you need to save document/presentation to keep these properties...

Comment: KazJaw ... you might want to paste that into an answer so Iban can mark it as one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've learnt, you need to actively save the document for it to keep hold of the CustomDocumentProperty values.